# Passing PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL to docker build

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am building an app that has a dependency available on a private Pypi server.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /src/mylib

COPY . ./

RUN pip install .
```

I want pip to use the extra server to install the dependencies. So I'm trying to pass the `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` environment variable during the build phase like so:

```
"docker build --pull -t $IMAGE_TAG --build-arg PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=$PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL ."
```

For some reason it is not working as intended, and `RUN echo $PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` returns nothing.

What is wrong?

Comment: Take a look this article: https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should add `ARG` to your `Dockerfile`. Your Dockerfile should look like this:

```
 FROM python:3.6

 ARG PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL 
 # YOU CAN ALSO SET A DEFAULT VALUE: 
 # ARG PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=DEFAULT_VALUE

 RUN echo "PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL = $PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL"
 # you could also use braces - ${PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL}

 WORKDIR /src/mylib     
 COPY . ./     
 RUN pip install .
```

If you want to know more, take a look [this article](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/).

Comment: I think you should also set the build-argument as environment variable to make it available to `pip install`: `ENV PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=${PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL}`

Comment: @isnot2bad nope, in this case you don't.

Comment: @freedev you are right! I didn't know that Dockerfile ARGs are exposed as environment variables at build time. I thought they are only usable within the Dockerfile (e.g. in a RUN instruction). But this totally make sense - thx!